# Rscript can not load ggplot2 package using PHP exec(), but it runs well in shell

Tags: php, r, exec, rstudio

I have already installed ggplot2 and Rcpp package; these run well when I am using shell, but fail if using `exec()` PHP

here my error log:

> Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : unable to load
>   shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
>   /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found
>   (required by /usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so) Error: package or
>   namespace load failed for â€˜ggplot2â€™ Execution halted

My server using centos 6.
While I got Rstudio from [here](http://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-rhel-0.99.903-x86_64.rpm) (v0.99.903-x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

My best guess -- versions of `libstdc++` are getting mixed and matched; it's possible that a version of `libstdc++` bundled with `lampp` is being used in lieu of the system `libstdc++`, and so R packages compiled against the system `libstdc++` are now failing to load against the version bundled with `lampp`.

I'm not sure what the best resolution here is -- you could try rebuilding `lampp` against the system version of `libstdc++`, or rebuild your R packages against the version of `libstdc++` provided by `lampp`?